# I am stuck with trying to make a single card appear out of the array while the rest kept inactive

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have an array of 12 cards and i am stuck with trying to make a single card appear out of the array while the rest kept inactive.

```
string name = "Card_" 
int deckcards;
public void shuffle_Deck()
    {
        //runs a random selection from the range and updates the namespace of the gametag
        deckcards = Random.Range(1, 13);
        tagName = name + deckcards;

        //printing to the console
        Debug.Log(tagName);
        //calling the gametag of the gameobject and setting the rest of the objects invisible;

        foreach (GameObject array in gameArray)
        {
            GameObject.FindWithTag(tagName).SetActive(true);
         //How do i set the rest to false


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use iteration through the whole deck the answer i think is:

```
foreach (GameObject array in gameArray)
{
    if(array.CompareTag(tagName))
    {
        array.SetActive(true);
    } 
    else 
    {
        array.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

i think this may solve the problem